# Entity frawork not work with azure db on azure website, but localy yes

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have problem with Entity framework. If I start web app localy thats all is right, but if I publish on azure then database not work. Localy I use same connection string to azure db, I do not have local database. Where can be problem?

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="AzureDbConnectionString"
         connectionString="Server=serverName.database.windows.net,1433;Database=UserName;User ID=UserName@serverName;Password=SuperPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Error: Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.

Peter

Comment: Did you check out what the error says?

Comment: Yes, but I do not understand why localy work, but on azure not

Comment: @AndrewBarber Some adviceplease?

Comment: You don't have it set up properly on Azure, apparently

Answer (score 0):

On the Azure portal, go to websites -> your website -> configure. Scroll down to "connection strings" and add your connection string there. Make sure you give it the same name as in your web.config file, (in your case "AzureDbConnectionString")